Calculate quarterly percentage increase and decrease in sql
I can simply use LAG() to calculate the percentage change from my table (see below) of this month compared to the data 3 months ago or 1 year ago.
But now, I want to get this result: calculate the sum of each quarter, and then get the percentage change (Q1 of the following year needs to be calculated with reference to Q4 of the previous year.)
For example:



year
quarter
total_num
quarter_change_pct




2021
1
1088030
0.00%


2021
2
1077857
-0.93%


2021
3
1048368
-2.74%


2021
4
992279
-5.35%


2022
1
1026123
3.41%


2022
2
1074024
4.67%


2022
3
1054501
-1.82%


2022
4
1080568
2.47%


2023
1
1001410
-7.33%


2023
2
961672
-3.97%


2023
3
979835
1.89%


2023
4
982167
0.24%



I don't know how to solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated if anyone can help.(BTW, the database I use supports the majority of PostgreSQL syntax, so you can also use PostgreSQL for demo, thanks!)
sample data:
create table tb1(
  date date,
  num int
);

insert into tb1 values
('2021-01-31', 359738),
('2021-02-28', 378564),
('2021-03-31', 349728),
('2021-04-30', 368945),  
('2021-05-31', 321456),
('2021-06-30', 387456),
('2021-07-31', 310567),
('2021-08-31', 342189),
('2021-09-30', 395612),
('2021-10-31', 278945),
('2021-11-30', 365478),
('2021-12-31', 347856),
('2022-01-31', 319478),
('2022-02-28', 382456),
('2022-03-31', 324189),
('2022-04-30', 395612),  
('2022-05-31', 367845),
('2022-06-30', 310567),
('2022-07-31', 382456),
('2022-08-31', 347856),
('2022-09-30', 324189),
('2022-10-31', 395612),
('2022-11-30', 319478),
('2022-12-31', 365478),
('2023-01-31', 302856),
('2023-02-28', 334531),
('2023-03-31', 364023),
('2023-04-30', 334534),  
('2023-05-31', 313678),
('2023-06-30', 313460),
('2023-07-31', 357281),
('2023-08-31', 314578),
('2023-09-30', 307976),
('2023-10-31', 304567),
('2023-11-30', 311378),
('2023-12-31', 366222);

My table looks like this(simplified):



date
num




2021-01-31
359738


2021-02-28
378564


2021-03-31
349728


2021-04-30
368945


2021-05-31
321456


2021-06-30
387456


2021-07-31
310567


2021-08-31
342189


2021-09-30
395612


2021-10-31
278945


2021-11-30
365478


2021-12-31
347856


2022-01-31
319478


2022-02-28
382456


2022-03-31
324189


2022-04-30
395612


2022-05-31
367845


2022-06-30
310567


2022-07-31
382456


2022-08-31
347856


2022-09-30
324189


2022-10-31
395612


2022-11-30
319478


2022-12-31
365478


2023-01-31
302856


2023-02-28
334531


2023-03-31
364023


2023-04-30
334534


2023-05-31
313678


2023-06-30
313460


2023-07-31
357281


2023-08-31
314578


2023-09-30
307976


2023-10-31
304567


2023-11-30
311378


2023-12-31
366222




I did edit your question. Now it starts with the question, and the long list of data is put add the end, because it's less important than the question. Because it's only needed when the problem is clear....

You have to use LAG and Quarter function to solve the issue in ProgreSQL.
QUARTER function return one of the following values:

1 if the date falls in January, February or March.
2 if the date falls in April, May or June.
3 if the date falls in July, August or September.
4 if the date falls in October, November or December.

LAG() function is a powerful window function that allows you to access data from a previous row within the same result set. It’s particularly useful for comparing values in the current row with values in the preceding row.
Finally, to get your result set the SQL script will be .
SELECT Year, QUARTER, total_num,  
to_char((total_num-(LAG(total_num,1) OVER (ORDER BY Year, QUARTER))) * 100 /(LAG(total_num,1) OVER (ORDER BY Year,QUARTER)), 'S990D99%')  as PCT 
FROM 
(SELECT EXTRACT('Year' FROM DATE) AS Year, 
EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM DATE) AS QUARTER, 
CAST (SUM(NUM) AS DECIMAL) AS total_num FROM tb1 GROUP BY Year, QUARTER 
ORDER BY Year,QUARTER);

Implement this work on PostgreSQL 17.
Thanks

Thanks! But it has a little issue. It seems to miss '0' when calculating the percentage. For example, the output of Q2 in 21 is -.93%, and the output of Q4 in 23 is +.24%.

@Joe,
Many thanks for your feedback. Make changes in my answer. Now the format of column PCT will be -
to_char((total_num-(LAG(total_num,1) OVER (ORDER BY Year, QUARTER))) * 100 /(LAG(total_num,1) OVER (ORDER BY Year,QUARTER)), 'S990D99%')  as PCT

This query may be a little complicated, but the result meets your requirements. I hope it can help you.
test on PostgreSQL 16: https://dbfiddle.uk/7W1SW7KH
WITH QuarterlyTotals AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year,
    EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date) AS quarter,
    SUM(num) AS total_num
  FROM tb1
  GROUP BY year,quarter
),
QuarterlyChanges AS (
  SELECT
    t1.year,
    t1.quarter,
    t1.total_num,
    COALESCE(t2.total_num, t1.total_num) AS prev_quarter_total
  FROM QuarterlyTotals t1
  LEFT JOIN QuarterlyTotals t2 ON (
    t1.year = t2.year AND t1.quarter = t2.quarter + 1
    OR (t1.year = t2.year + 1 AND t1.quarter = 1 AND t2.quarter = 4)
  )
)
SELECT
  year,
  quarter,
  total_num,
  ROUND((total_num - prev_quarter_total)::numeric / prev_quarter_total * 100, 2) || '%' AS quarter_change_pct
FROM QuarterlyChanges
ORDER BY  year, quarter;

